# Get IP address on RaspberryPi 4 running Yocto image

Tags: raspberry-pi, ip, yocto, scp, meta-raspberrypi

I used bitbake to generate a Linux image for my raspberry pi 4 board following the instructions provided in the meta-raspberrypi layer (https://github.com/agherzan/meta-raspberrypi). I am able to connect to my board using an FTDI USB to UART cable and running minicom on my host machine. However, I need to transfer files to my board using SCP. For that, I need the IP address and when I execute "ip a" command in my RPi4 board, I get the output below showing no IP address that I can use. Can you please provide some guidance? Do I need to add something to my conf or bblayers files?

```
root@raspberrypi4-64:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:57:bb:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:57:bb:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since RaspberryPi 4 has both Ethernet and WiFi interfaces available, you can connect to a network using one or the other (or both).

If you have a cable connected to your Ethernet port, you just need to request a DHCP lease. You should be able to do that by running `udhcpc -i eth0`. If `udhcpc` command is not available, you'll need to find the recipe providing it (might be hidden in a Busybox configuration file though) or add any other DHCP client to your image.

If you plan to connect to your network over WiFi, you need first to connect to the network and then request a DHCP lease. The former can be done with `wpa_supplicant`, `connman`, `nmcli`, etc. They probably aren't available in your image so you would need to add one first. To connect with `wpa_supplicant`, do the following: `wpa_passphrase "<SSID>" > wpa.conf` replacing `<SSID>` with the `SSID` (name) of the network you want to connect to. It'll then wait for you to input the password of this network. Then, run `wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -cwpa.conf&`. This will start a connection in background. If the connection is successful in the logs, you can continue. Then, run `udhcpc -iwlan0` to get a DHCP lease and then you're good to go!

If there are no DHCP server on your network (direct connection to your host machine for example), you need to assign an IP address manually with e.g.: `ip addr add <IP addr> dev <iface>` replacing `<IP addr>` with a valid (in the same subnet as the other computer(s) in the network) IP address (and maybe subnet after it? e.g. `192.168.1.153/24`) and `<iface>` with `eth0` or `wlan0`.

Comment: Thanks, @qschulz. I think for rpi4, a wired ethernet connection might be best. However, I expect to be developing for target hardware in the future with no ethernet block, and wifi code won't be up and running initially. I am wondering how I am going to transfer/debug code? Most of my experience is on ARM Cotex platforms, which use either JTAG or some serial connection (ex: UART/USB). Is there a method or an option I am missing? I wonder how android phones developers load/debug their code. There isn't an ethernet port, and I would think wifi is not the best dev connection. Any thoughts? Thx!

Comment: If you have USB OTG support, you can use fastboot, or adb which are extensively used on Android AFAIK. Otherwise, if you only have USB host, try to get your hands on a USB to Ethernet adapter and compile in the appropriate drivers in your bootloader and kernel so that you can download a new kernel/rootfs/dtb from the bootloader and also send files to/from a running Linux on your target. If you're looking to send very small files, you can still use kermit or similar serial protocols but the bandwidth is obviously horrendous (= baudrate of your serial).

Comment: I will have USB OTG support, and both fastboot and adb would be really useful. I think this is the way I am going to go. I thought I'd try it first on my RP4, but I didn't know how to add these tools to my yocto build. I did a quick search and couldn't find the appropriate layer to add. If you have any input, that would be great. I created a separate post for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66209136/adb-yocto-recipe. Thx!