# ADB Yocto Recipe

Tags: adb, yocto, raspberry-pi4

Is there a recipe I can add to a yocto build to enable Android Debug Bridge (ADB)? I built a basic image for a raspberry pi 4 using yocto bitbake (pokey+meta-raspberry). I want to be able to communicate with the board using USB instead of ethernet/ssh. ADB seems to be a good option (ex: adb push). I reviewed the meta-raspberry layer, and I didn't see such a feature to add, so I wonder if there is a layer I could use. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

`android-tools` in `meta-openembedded/meta-oe` layer is the package recipe for Android related tools, such as `fastboot` and `adb`. See https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/52988/.

Therefore, you probably want to install `android-tools` package in your image and maybe `android-tools-adbd` too?

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestion. I was able to include ADB in my RPI image following your instructions but I cannot connect to my RPI4 using adb from my dev laptop. I have another dev board (snapdragon) which I can connect to using adb using the same laptop. I connect my RPI4 to my laptop using the RPI USB-C port assuming it supports USB OTG. I verified that adb was included in my RPI4 by running the adb command on the RPI console. In fact, I am able to connect to my other dev board from my RPI4 using adb and one of the USB type-A ports. Any input would be appreciated. Thx!

Comment: My guess is that `adb` is the client connecting to `adbd` server so you'd need to run `adbd` on the RPi4 and connect to it with `adb` from your dev laptop.